# neighbourhood reverse geocoding-geonames api error code 15-R language

Tags: r, reverse-geocoding, geonames

I am encountering a problem with the reverse geocoding geonames api package in R. I have a dataset  of nearly 900k rows containing latitude and longtitude and I am using GNneighbourhood(lat,lng)$name function to create the neighbourhood for every pair of coordinates(my dataset contains incidents in San Francisco).

Now, while the function is working perfectly for the big majority of points, there are times that it is giving error code 15 message :we are afraid we could not find a neighbourhood for latitude and longitude. The same procedure can be performes with revgeocode function(google reverse geocoding api) of the ggmap package and in fact it works right even for the points that give error with geoname package. The reason I am not using it is cause of the query limit per day.

**Successful example**

```
GNneighbourhood(37.7746,-122.4259)$name
[1] "Western Addition"
```

**Failure**

```
GNneighbourhood(37.76569,-122.4718)$name
Error in getJson("neighbourhoodJSON", list(lat = lat, lng = lng)) : 
  error code 15 from server: we are afraid we could not find a neighbourhood for latitude and longitude :37.76569,-122.4718
```

Searching for the above point in google maps works fine and we can also see that the incident is not on water or any other inappropriate location.(Unless the park nearby is indicating something, i don't know) [image]

Anyone with experience with the procedure and the specific package? Is it possible for the api to be incomplete? It clearly states that it can handle all US cities. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are reporting some error but the illustration is not throwing one. The Western Addition _is_ a San Francisco neighborhood. San Francisco is surrounded on three sides by water and the geonames API will not report a neighborhood if the coordinates are in the water.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question  and cleared things up I think.

Comment: Google Maps shows that location as in the middle of Lincoln Way. If you move it slightly south (lat=37.76560), you get "Inner Sunset". The same issue you face applies to all of Golden Gate Park in the the experiments I ran with the "demo" option. I think the blank locations are not in postal zipcodes which seems to be the focus of Geonames project. Does make you wonder how mail gets to the de Young Museum.

Comment: I tried to recover postal codes for every pair of coordinates as you mentioned and indeed it seems to work smoothly.  Since you are aware of the problem, do you have any ideas to bypass it? I am thinking whether I can turn coordinates to postal codes and then map them to the corresponding neighbourhood ( my experiments are still unsuccessful on this)